# How to successfully create a dialog fragment with recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

'Here is my adapter class code and when i long pressed on an item it should show a alert dialog box to delete that item ..I want to call DialogFragmnent from recycled view. How to resolve this show method from Recyclerview adapter. How is it possible?

> Adaptorclass

```
package com.example.recyclerview1;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.LinearLayout;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
        import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
        import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
        import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.LinkedList;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        public class MyAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdaptor.MyViewHolder>{
            ArrayList<Student> l;
            Context c;
            public MyAdaptor (Context ctx,ArrayList<Student> list)
            {
                l=list;
                c =ctx;
            }
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
                strong textMyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
                return myViewHolder;

            }
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
                final Student s = l.get(position);
                holder.t1.setText(s.getName());
                holder.t2.setText(s.getCnic());
            int currentposition=position;
            final Student infodata= l.get(position);

                holder.linearLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View view)
                    {


                        Dialogclass dialog = new Dialogclass();
                        dialog.show(((AppCompatActivity)c).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Fragment");
                        removieitem(infodata);
                        Toast.makeText(c," Removed item "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });


                holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(c,s.getName()+" "+s.getCnic(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            private void removieitem(Student infodata) {
                int position=l.indexOf(infodata);
                l.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }


            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return l.size();
            }
            class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                TextView t1,t2;
                LinearLayout linearLayout;
                public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
                {
                    super(itemView);
                    t1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
                    t2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtcnic);
                    linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
                }
            }
        }
```

> Dialogclass

```
package com.example.recyclerview1;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

public class Dialogclass extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
            // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
            return builder.create();
        }
    }
```

**It show the Error as....java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
        at com.example.recyclerview1.MyAdaptor$1.onLongClick(MyAdaptor.java:49)**

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.recyclerview1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ArrayList<Student> list=  list = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView rc;


    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rc = findViewById(R.id.myrec);
        Student s1 = new Student("Ahmed","34198723482");
        Student s2 = new Student("Ahmed","34198723482");
        Student s3 = new Student("Ahmed","34198723482");
        Student s4 = new Student("Ahmed","34198723482");
        Student s5 = new Student("Ahmed","34198723482");
        Student s6 = new Student("Ahmed","34198723482");
        Student s7 = new Student("Ahmed","34198723482");
        Student s8 = new Student("Ahmed","34198723482");
        Student s9 = new Student("Ahmed","34198723482");
        Student s0 = new Student("Ahmed","34198723482");

        list.add(s1);
        list.add(s2);
        list.add(s3);
        list.add(s4);
        list.add(s5);
        list.add(s6);
        list.add(s7);
        list.add(s8);
        list.add(s9);
        list.add(s0);

        MyAdaptor myAdaptor = new MyAdaptor(getApplicationContext(),list);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rc.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        rc.setAdapter(myAdaptor);


    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are passing the application context in MyAdapter constructor. Can you add the code for where you are initializing your adapter in activity?

Comment: ok i added code check it..

Comment: Change  this line ```MyAdaptor myAdaptor = new MyAdaptor(MainActivity.this,list)```; and also this ```dialog.show(((MainActivity)c).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Fragment");```

Comment: why do you want to create DialogFragment in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Problem at line below

```
dialog.show(((AppCompatActivity)c).getSupportFragmentManager()
```

c is Context so cannot be cast to **AppCombatActivity**

Try Sending Activity object in `MyAdaptor` class like below

```
public MyAdaptor (Activity ctx,ArrayList<Student> list)
```

and In  `MainActivity.java` class you need to pass Activity object like this below -

```
MyAdaptor myAdaptor = new MyAdaptor(MainActivity.this,list);
```

Comment: I have already send activity object like this in MyAdaptor class...

Comment: As your error says you are sending android.app.Application object in Adapter class.

Comment: In MainActivity class you need to pass like this below -

MyAdaptor myAdaptor = new MyAdaptor(MainActivity.this,list);

and Update your Adapter constructor to below - 
MyAdaptor (Activity ctx,ArrayList<Student> list)

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom dialog.

Add `RecyclerView` in your XML file layout if don't have any layout create it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fl_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="300dp">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then initialize your `RecyclerView` and any other view in `onCreateView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //TODO Change 'frag_mdialog' to your custom view XML layout 
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_mdialog, container, false);
    view = v;

    // Do all the stuff to initialize your custom view

    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_dialog);

    return v;
}
```

I hope this help you.